# can not install react-native-community/react-native-netinfo

Tags: react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

I want to remove "Warning: NetInfo has been extracted from react-native core
and will be removed in a future release.
It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/netinfo'
instead of 'react-native'. 
See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo" But when i run command it doesn't work.

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/netinfo
```

[image: Preview of error when run code]

Comment: i had used Windows Power Shell to run this command. It gets error. After using cmd it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the @ in the name of the package powershell treats it as a variable.

You could fix this by either using cmd.exe or putting the package name in quotes like this: `npm install --save "@react-native-community/netinfo"`

Answer (score 0):

Actual, [@Rik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4076066/rik)'s Answer is correct. i would like to add more..

1. `npm install --save "@react-native-community/netinfo"` 
   run this Command with quotations.
2. `cd android`  go to your android Project directory
3. `gradlew clean` run this to clean your android project
4. then run either `react-native run-android` or `npx react-native run-android` or whatever command you use to start project.